# Linux shell - check and set last byte of a binary file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a set of files that I want to process. I have no control over the files creation or deletion.
However I know that the last byte of each file is always xFF and is unused.

I want to process the files and modify the last byte so I can tell they have been processed. I can't find any specific examples of single byte operations in the shell.

Pseudo-code

```
for file in *
do
if (lastbyteof($file) == xFF)
then
    # Process this file
    ...
    # Mark the file so we don't process it again
    lastbyteof($file) = xF0
fi
```

Comment: When you have no control of the files, how are you sure that your file's last byte even before processing, is already `0xFF` ? I'm just asking this because if you're processing a set of files, using such a tag to mark the files is a really bad approach. Instead track the list of files you've processed by maintaining the data in a separate location, may be another data structure, a file, or a database, etc.

Comment: The files are 32-bit bitmaps, but the alpha channel is not used. Every 4th byte in the image data is 0xFF
I wanted to avoid creating and maintaining meta-data when a simple byte flag would not change the true value of the bitmap and should be easily checked.

Comment: look for solutions that use `od -c $file`. Can't remember how you change the data, but I know I've seen people do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my requirement from the last byte to the fourth and processed it like this.
Any improvements or alternate suggestions are very welcome.

```
for file in *.ts
do
    # Get the value of the fourth byte (skip the first 3)
    checkByte=`hexdump -n1 -s3 -e'"" 1/1 "%02xf"' "$file"`
    if [ $checkByte == "ff" ]
    then
        # Process this file

        # Change the fourth byte to 0xFE
        echo -ne \\xFE | dd conv=notrunc bs=1 count=1 seek=3 of="$file"
    fi
done
```